# Retrieve annotation text in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a Google Chart in my site and I want to redirect the user to other page once he/she/it clicks in a value.

To do that I'm using the select event like this:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
    // Selected item
    var item = chart.getSelection()[0];
});
```

The problem is that I have no idea on how to get the annotation text that is what I need. A quick example will be useful here. For example, [in this chart](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart), if I click in the highest point of the blue line I would like to retrieve the text: "G". Just this text, I don't need "Cats: 8".

Is this possible? How could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `data.getValue()`

```js
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(args) {
   if (chart.getSelection().length>0) {
     var selection = chart.getSelection()[0];
     var annotationText=data.getValue(selection.row, 0);
     //redirect with annotationText = 'D' here
     //..
   }
});
```

See this fiddle based on the google playground example above -> **http://jsfiddle.net/F7WVG/**

Comment: You should test the length of a selection, as the select event fires when a user deselects a point as well, so the length of the array returned by `chart.getSelection()` can be 0, which would make `chart.getSelection()[0]` throw an error.

Comment: @asgallant, You are absolutely right. Thank you for pointing that out. Have updated the answer and the jsfiddle as well.

Comment: @asgallant , is any way to get the annotationText(mouse over) of the bar chart. Im using this method to add the annotation to my bar graph[chartData.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotationText'});]

Comment: Use a `onmouseover` event handler.  When the user mouses over a data point (or an annotation) the event fires and passes an object to the handler with `row` and `column` properties that you can use to get the data you want.